# Text shifts one character to the left when moving upwards

Tags: neovim, terminal, wsl

When I move the cursor upwards, the whole line (including the number) shifts one character to the left. The GIF explains it the best.

I'm using Neovim installed in Windows but opened through WSL running on Windows Terminal. This doesn't happen if I open Neovim directly from Windows, only when I open it through the terminal. I've tried some simple fixes - turning off themes and disabling numbers, but I can't think of how to troubleshoot this.

[image]

Comment: Do you have it with a bare configuration?  `nvim -i NONE -u NONE`?

Comment: just a guess: `:set conceallevel=0 concealcursor=`

Comment: Both of these solutions didn't work, sadly, but I disabled the cursorline and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - apparently the cursorline was causing this bug. Not sure what the root cause is, but disabling that fixed this issue.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem and posted an answer. Would be great if somebody could explain the root cause.